# How to cleanup old Failed Builds in TeamCity?

Tags: build, continuous-integration, teamcity

We do have hundreds of failed builds in TeamCity (number is especially high because of old retry on fail settings) and now it's a pain to browse history.

I want to clean up only old failed builds, is there anyway to do that in TeamCity?  Normal clean-up policy only allows X days before the last successful build sort of clean ups.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried to find a "delete build history record" but I couldn't find one.  That doesn't prove it isn't there, but it it was, it would be an opportunity for devs to abuse it as some PM's use the history as a metric that may say something about code quality.  If we could delete all the failed builds, it would make this statistic game-able.

Of course there is the policy page which has some tuning, but not the sort you mentioned (you can't remove just failed builds)
admin/cleanupPolicies.html

You might want to pin your favorite builds (which should protect them from clean up) and then change the policy to clean up everything 1 day old, then change the policy back to something more reasonable.

Comment: Nice idea to pin only needed (e.g. successful) builds, cleanup all, and then unpin! Works though only for small number of builds ))

Comment: TeamCity has a permission model that could (and does) restrict the ability to remove builds to project admins. Ordinary devs don't necessarily need to have that permission if there is concern that they might 'game the system'.

Answer (score 69):

In more recent versions of TeamCity you can now:

1. Click on the build you want to remove.
2. From the Build Actions menu select Remove...
3. Put in an optional comment and click the Remove button to remove that build.

Comment: Tested and confirmed in version 9.0.3

Comment: will this delete the artifact itself?

Comment: It's a bit arduous to do this for a pile of builds - say that you inadvertently caused by making a trigger run continuously over the weekend. Going to have to break out some REST, I think.

Comment: I can't see any option to remove a build in v2022.x

Answer (score 25):

There is a way to delete a build and it is using REST protocol: http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TW/REST+API+Plugin

```
Get details of a specific build:
GET http://teamcity:8111/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/<buildLocator>
(also supports DELETE to delete a build)
```

To run this you need a REST client. I've used [a plugin for Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/restclient/), which is quite nice. But any REST client should do the work.
It makes sense first trying on the test TeamCity instance, as you won't have a chance to recover deleted build, except from backup.

**Update**

New version of TeamCity (since 8?) supports deleting builds naturally. Hey-hey!! ))

Just go to the build page, then Actions > Remove ...

Comment: Thanks for the update. Everywhere else people suggest to do crazy http requests to API.