# "Reset" buildNumber after deleting old builds in TeamCity

Tags: .net, build, teamcity, teamcity-9.0

Acording to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2947910/how-to-cleanup-old-failed-builds-in-teamcity) I found out how to delete builds in Teamcity

This works fine. So an example:
I have 20 builds and I delete build 12 till 20. So my last buildnumber is 11. But when I execute a new build it's buildnumber 21.

Is it possible to start the next build at number 12 (again)?

I know it's not a good approach. But this is for testing purposes and we don't want to many buildnumbers. I know this is not something we will use in a real environment.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can update the next build number via the "Build counter" field on the project configuration settings page.